# How to set XmlWriter.XmlWriterSettings when created from XPathNavigator.AppendChild()?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xmlwriter

I need to set the OmitXmlDeclaration property of the XmlWriterSettings for a XmlWriter to false to not have XML declarations created. The issue is that I have created the XmlWriter from a call of a XPathNavigator.AppendChild() method. Code below:

```
    public String GetEntityXml<T>(List<T> entities)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();

        using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
        {

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name + "_LIST"));
            ser.Serialize(writer, entities);
        }

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);

        string resultString = stringWriter.ToString();

        stringWriter.Close();
        xmlTextWriter.Close();

        return resultString;
    }
```

Any idea how to serialize the List and not have XML declarations?

Comment: In my answer, I assumed you are trying to add the serialized xml to an existing document. Is that the case? Also, do you need to omit the xml declaration from resultString?

Comment: rsbarro -- you are correct. I am looking at getting a xml serialization of a collection of entities and then adding it to a combined document with several serializations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not getting the XML declaration when I execute your code. Serializing a `List<int>` gives me:

```
<Int32_LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <int>5</int>
  <int>7</int>
  <int>2</int>
</Int32_LIST>
```

Note that the “XML declaration” that `OmitXmlDeclaration` refers to is typically something similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

If you’re instead referring to the `xmlns` parts, then those are called “XML *namespace* declarations”, and may be eliminated by initializing an `XmlSerializerNamespaces` instance with a default empty namespace, and passing it to your `Serialize` method:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name + "_LIST"));
var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("", "") });
ser.Serialize(writer, entities, namespaces);
```

The below is a shortened implementation which achieves the same result as your code:

```
public String GetEntityXml<T>(List<T> entities)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name + "_LIST"));
        var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("", "") });
        ser.Serialize(writer, entities, namespaces);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I think the sample code is a little misleading. I assumed that he's trying to add children to an already existing XML document, in which case the `XmlSerializer` does write out the xml declaration and cause his sample code to crash. Take the sample code and add the following after the xmlDoc is declared and you'll see what I mean: `xmlDoc.LoadXml("<test></test>"); var nav = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator();`

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. The creation of the `XPathNavigator` seemed too pointless, given that he already knew he could initialize `XmlWriter` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach (switched to `var` for readability):

```
public String GetEntityXml<T>(List<T> entities)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    var nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        //Create an XmlWriter that will omit xml declarations
        var s = new XmlWriterSettings{ OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw, s))
        {
            //Use the following to serialize without namespaces
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>),
                          new XmlRootAttribute(typeof(T).Name + "_LIST"));
            ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, entities, ns);
        }

        //Pass xml string to nav.AppendChild()
        nav.AppendChild(sw.ToString());
    }

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
        }
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Rather than using `nav.AppendChild()` to create the `XmlWriter`, you can create the `XmlWriter` separately and then just use `nav.AppendChild(string)` to write the XML into `xmlDoc`. When you create the `XmlWriter` yourself, you can omit the XML declaration. Also, when you serialize, you'll probably want to omit the `xmlns:xsi` and `xmlns:xsd` namespaces using the `XmlSerializerNamespaces` class.

Comment: -1: Please replace `new XmlTextWriter()` with `XmlWriter.Create()` and I'll upvote.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Updated, but I was just copying the code from the OP. I don't think that part of code is relevant to the question he is asking. =] I'm pretty sure he's trying to figure out how to insert the serialized xml into an existing xml document (since there are far simpler ways to write the `GetEntityXml` method, as the other answer clearly points out).

Comment: +1 Readers copy and paste the code we post, even if we intend it as an example of something else. BTW, I'm letting you get away with no `using` blocks because I'm in a good mood.

Comment: I hear you, will update that as well. I was trying to not get too far from the original just to illustrate the changes I was suggesting, but I see your point.